# Pandas - Correlation between two dataframes without alignment

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

I need to get the correlation between two dataframes columns. Both of them have the same columns but the correlation is not working because of alignment probably.

I don't really care about the index of the dataframe, i just wan't to correlate the values in the cells, treating each column as a random distribution.

I'm not sure if it's my pandas or my math skills that are lacking, but i don't get what is the purpose of the alignment in this case.

**Here is my code:**

```
def correlation(indv1, indv2):
    frame1 = pd.DataFrame(indv1).select_dtypes(include=['float64', 'int64']) # Filtra o individuo para ficar apenas com valores int ou float
    frame2 = pd.DataFrame(indv2).select_dtypes(include=['float64', 'int64'])
    result = frame1.corrwith(frame2)
    return result.sum()
```

**Here is what i've tried:**

- aligning the dataframes with `DataFrame.align`, but i'm not sure how to do it
- reindexing the dataframes with `DataFrame.reindex` but it also generates NaN from alignment
- using `DataFrame.reset_index` but it creates another column with the old indexes

**Here is a sample that is going wrong:**

```
test1 = pd.Series(np.random.random(3), index=[0, 1, 2])
test2 = pd.Series(np.random.random(3), index=[3, 4, 5])
print(correlation(test1, test2))
```

If you print the result array of the correlation function, it shows NaN.

**Here is what i want to do (per column):**

[image: correlation formula]

with X being a value from the cell and mi and sigma being the mean and std. dev. of the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're neglecting the mathematical index for the summation.  Those are `(Xi - muX)(Yi - muY)`.  It definitely matters how they are aligned.

If you don't care to align the indices but want to correlate on their existing order and you know that the lengths are the same, try this instead:

```
def correlation(indv1, indv2):
    frame1 = pd.DataFrame(indv1).select_dtypes(include=['float64', 'int64']) # Filtra o individuo para ficar apenas com valores int ou float
    frame2 = pd.DataFrame(indv2).select_dtypes(include=['float64', 'int64'])
    # Part I changed                /--------------------\
    result = frame1.corrwith(frame2.set_index(frame1.index))
    return result.sum()
```

---

**Demo**

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
test1 = pd.Series(np.random.random(3), index=[0, 1, 2])
test2 = pd.Series(np.random.random(3), index=[3, 4, 5])
print(correlation(test1, test2))

-0.719774418655
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I think I got it all wrong. I thought the correlation was applied to the cartesian product of X and Y, but i think this only applies to joint distributions. Well, i have to redo everything then.